# Pulling additional data from a Locust response

Tags: response, locust

I am running a load test using `Locust` and have it working fine except I want to get the the sub-status code return in the response. I know the status code is available with `response.status_code` but I need additional information such as `response.sub_status_code`. Is this currently available in Locust?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. There is no sign of it in a documentation. Anyway, there are some details from [another Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/787117/3866610) why substatus is problematic. It's about `.Net` platform but I found it interesting

> See the second-to-last response here:
>   http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t73739-sending-status-as-4011.html.
>   The HTTP RFC doesn't define sub-codes
>   (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). It looks
>   like it may be an MS only thing - see last response in the first link,
>   which then points to here:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode.aspx.
>   While that is how to SET the sub- statuscode, not retrieve it, the
>   interesting thing to me is that it is only supported "with the
>   integrated pipeline mode in IIS 7.0 and at least the .NET Framework
>   version 3.0."
>
> The only other thing I can think of is to look into the HRESULT in the
>   ErrorCode property on the HttpException and see if there's something
>   going on at the bit level where you can figure out the code and
>   sub-code from that.